# Add twitter share button to each blog post on tumblr

Tags: twitter, tumblr

I'm working on a tumblr blog and I would like to add the twitter share button at the end of each blog post. I know how to get the button for the code and I've been able to get it on a post successfully. However I want it to be on all my post so I don't want to have to add the code at the end of each blog posts's html.

I thought I could avoid this by putting the code in my blogs html. I added in between the `block:Post` and `/block:Post`. This works for the most part, the only thing is that when I'm on my blog the link shows up on the post preview and shows how many shares my blog has had and while I'm on an individual post it shows how many shares the post has.

How can I add it such that it only shows the number of shares the post has and will be added to each post automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job:

http://ialreadydontlikeyou.tumblr.com/post/1167220523/implementing-the-tweet-button-on-posts-in-tumblr#.U7_VW41_v_E

It needs special workaround, as you need to place many tweet buttons on the same page.